# Displaying layers name in the browser console on every zoom level in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have displayed multiple tile layers in OpenLayers. Now I want to display layers name in the browser console on every zoom level.

This is my code:

```
var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    name: "osm",
  }),

  new ol.layer.Tile({
    //   extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
      params: { LAYERS: "cite:india1", TILED: true },
      serverType: "geoserver",
      transition: 0,
      crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    }),
  }),

  new ol.layer.Tile({
    //   extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
      // params: {'LAYERS': 'cite:india1,cite:india2,cite:india3,cite:india4,cite:india5,cite:india6,cite:india7,cite:india8,cite:india9,cite:india10,cite:india11,cite:india12,cite:india13,cite:india14,cite:india15,cite:india16', 'TILED': true},
      params: { LAYERS: "cite:india16", TILED: true },
      serverType: "geoserver",
      transition: 0,
      crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    }),
  }),

  new ol.layer.Tile({
    //   extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
      // params: {'LAYERS': 'cite:india1,cite:india2,cite:india3,cite:india4,cite:india5,cite:india6,cite:india7,cite:india8,cite:india9,cite:india10,cite:india11,cite:india12,cite:india13,cite:india14,cite:india15,cite:india16', 'TILED': true},
      params: { LAYERS: "cite:india15", TILED: true },
      serverType: "geoserver",
      transition: 0,
      crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    }),
  }),
];

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: "map",
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-85.685, 39.891],
    //   -85.685, 39.891
    // -10997148, 4569099
    zoom: 3,
  }),
});
```

Comment: I cannot really tell what you want to achieve. Please edit the question and provide e.g. screenshots or a more detailed description including what you have tried so far, then we can try to help with that.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you mean by "display layers name in the browser console on every zoom level". Layers do not change with zoom change, so every time names of all the layers would be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the name for `layers` instead of using `name` in the layer.

```
layers.set('name', 'your_layer_name');
var nameLayers = layers.get('name');
console.log(nameLayers);
```

Comment: I think @rajdip wants to display the layer names in the browser console, not as a symbol on the tiles.

Comment: Oops! My bad. I was confused

Comment: @Jayzz i wants layer name on browser console

Comment: I'm updated my answer.